# MySQL ADD CONSTRAINT 18+

Tags: mysql, constraints

I need to know how do I ADD CONSTRAINT to a field and make sure that they are 18+ the field is age.

I can see how the following works, by joining the ID and the lastname to make the PersonID, but how do I get it to work to make sure a persons birthdate is 18 or over

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName);
```

I know how to check the DOB

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age FROM `members`
```

but how do I put that into an ADD CONSTRAINT.

Comment: It would be as simple as adding a constraint `check (age >= 18)` in almost any other DBMS. But MySQL has not implemented `check` constraints so you'll have to enforce this through your insert/update statements or with triggers.

Comment: And it would be a bit more complicated if you stored the birthdate and not the age (as you should because birthdate doesn't change. What do you plan to do, update the `age` column once a year? Or every day?

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than *simple* constraints (like foreign key references) is generally done with [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) in a DBMS.

You'll need a `before` trigger on the `insert` and `update` actions, to ensure you fail if either of those two try to set the age to something below 18.

If you want to simply *enforce* the column being a specific minimum value, you can just modify it in the `insert` or `update` trigger:

```
new.colname = 18
```

or leave it as it was in the `update` trigger:

```
new.colname = old.colname
```

To force a *failure,* you can [raise a signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) within the trigger.

> As an aside, it's rather unusual to store an *age* in the database (if this is indeed what you're doing) since this is obviously something that will need to be updated every year. A more sensible approach would be to store the birthdate which *doesn't* change, and simply get the age as a calculated field.

Comment: I think OP indicated that "birthdate" was being stored, not age. (Or, maybe I inferred that from the question because that's what I expected.)  The check for "age at least 18" could easily be performed on value assigned to `birthdate` column.... `NEW.birthdate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR`.

Comment: @spencer7593, yeah, I originally thought that but then re-read it. OP talks of adding a constraint to a field and specifically names that field as `age`.  Still, it's just an aside, I'll change it to "*if* you're doing X, Y may be better".

Comment: I know but this is a college thing

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's considered best practice to implement "business logic" such as this in the application, rather than in the database. Database constraints should generally only be used as a precaution to ensure that invalid data cannot enter your database: for instance, they can be used to ensure that foreign keys refer to valid objects, that required values are not inappropriately empty or zero, and so on. Under normal operation, it should be impossible to cause a constraint to be violated from the "front end" of your application.

One of the primary reasons for this is that it is often difficult to convert database errors (e.g, `invalid value for column 'age'`, or something of the sort) into errors which can be usefully displayed to users (e.g, a dialog box saying "you must be 18 years old to continue"). Additionally, it is often difficult or even impossible to permit exceptions to database constraints, or to allow existing violations to be "grandfathered in" when a new constraint is introduced.

So… *don't do this*. Check the user's age in the section of your application which handles creating users (e.g, your registration script), and/or any other sections which would allow their age to be changed; or in the object which represents a user in your application.